# Flutter Table Calendar: CalendarController Question

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So according to the changelog of table calendar ver. 3.0.0, `CalendarController` is removed. I have it on my codes and it's now showing up as an error [Undefined class 'CalendarController'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTrbZ.png). And now, I'm wondering what to do about it because i've found no answers to it anywhere.
Also, can someone explain to me what was the use of `CalendarController` in the first place?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: Just remove it. If you are not using it

Comment: I tried that but some other codes from my tablecalendar still gets an error which led me to believe that those codes relied on CalendarController-- but i'm not sure. :( i'm so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the changelog says, CalendarController is removed in the newer version.
It was used for the highlighted (currently selected) day functionalities.

You can manually configure the selected day by adding these attributes to the **TableCalender()**:

```
selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
      // Use `selectedDayPredicate` to determine which day is currently selected.
      // If this returns true, then `day` will be marked as selected.

      // Using `isSameDay` is recommended to disregard
      // the time-part of compared DateTime objects.
      return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
    },
    onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
      if (!isSameDay(_selectedDay, selectedDay)) {
        // Call `setState()` when updating the selected day
        setState(() {
          _selectedDay = selectedDay;
          _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        });
      }
    },
    onFormatChanged: (format) {
      if (_calendarFormat != format) {
        // Call `setState()` when updating calendar format
        setState(() {
          _calendarFormat = format;
        });
      }
    },
    onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
      // No need to call `setState()` here
      _focusedDay = focusedDay;
    },
```

Also make sure to define **firstDay:, lastDay:, and focusedDay:** because it is required by the TableCalendar() function, and also set the calendarFormat.

Refer official table_calendar example: https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/basics_example.dart